# Можно ли вкладывать блочные элементы в строчные?

Tags: html

Есть ли разница между `<h2><a>content<a/></h2> и <a><h2>content</h2></a>`

При переделывании проекта вдруг возник вопрос - А есть ли разница? Не нарушает ли это семантику?

Comment: "Миллион" лет назад разница была. Сейчас можно вкладывать блочные элементы в строчные.

Comment: Вроде раньше нарушало может и сейчас

Comment: @Duoxx, можно....  Не нарушает...

Comment: Ну я так редко делаю, считаю это немного странным. Но это выбор каждого.

Comment: Описание старой спецификации  https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2

Comment: Описание изменений спецификации  https://www.w3.org/TR/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: А это источник https://habr.com/company/htmlacademy/blog/336638/

Comment: @Air, _Сейчас можно вкладывать блочные элементы в строчные_ - не все и не во все

Comment: @Grundy, Ну думаю, что это не плохо было бы описать более подробным ответом.

Comment: @Air, ага, как только по свободнее буду постараюсь :-)

Comment: Спасибо, ребята.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Миллион" лет назад разница была. Сейчас можно вкладывать блочные элементы в строчные. (c)  Air

Comment: Вам бы на соревнование по "копипасту"...

Comment: Многое повидал, но шоб чужой коммент в место ответа...)))))

Answer (score 3):

Спецификация определяет какие элементы может хранить описываемый элемент в секции [`Content Model`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#content-model)

Для элемента `A` в этой секции указано следующее:

> Transparent, but there must be no interactive content or a element descendants.

> *Transparent*, однако не должно быть *интерактивных* элементов, или вложенных *<a>*

Под [интерактивными](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#interactive-content-2) в данном случае имеются ввиду следующие:

- `<a>` если атрибут `href` установлен
- `<audio>`  если атрибут `controls` установлен
- `<button>`
- `<details>`
- `<embed>`
- `<iframe>`
- `<img>`  если атрибут `usemap` установлен
- `<input>` если атрибут `type` не равен `hidden`
- `<label>`
- `<select>`
- `<textarea>`
- `<video>` если атрибут `controls` установлен

---

[Component Model: Transparent](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#transparent), означает, что компонентная модель будет применена такая же как и у родительского элемента.

Следовательно если какой-то элемент не может быть в родительском элементе, то он не может быть и в элементе `<a>` вложенном в родительский.

Если у элемента с `Transparent` компонентной моделью нет родителя, то считается, что он может хранить [`flow content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#flow-content-2) (в который входит и `h2`).

Из этого следует, что если ссылка находится непосредственно в теге `body` (например), который имеет `component model: Flow Content`, то запись

```
<a><h2>content</h2></a>
```

Вполне допустима, если же ссылка находится, например, внутри `<p>` элемента, который имеет [`component model: Phrasing content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#phrasing-content-2), то уже недопустима.